# Returning first x items from array : 3

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.4

Suppose I have this array :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 100828698
        [token] => 123
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 100828698
        [token] => fdsfsdfsd
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 100829014
        [token] => oidshiufjsd
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 100829014
        [token] => sdjfdhskjfdsh
    )

)
```

I try like this, but it is not so properly :

```
$count = count($lastviewedarticles);
if($count>=3)
    array_shift($lastviewedarticles);
    $lastviewedarticles[] = $articleid;
}
```

Do you have other ideas?

The result should be

```
1. If count(array) > 3  
2. Make a call of db
3. Fetch first 3 elements
4. Get next 3 elements
etc...
```

This situation a need to impliment

Comment: `$part = array_slice($lastviewedarticles, 0, 3);`?

Comment: Yes but if I have an array with 100 elements ?

Comment: Then you can still use `array_slice`

Comment: show how should look the expected output

Comment: The ideea is that after each 3 items I need to do a new foreach for this array and. If is a new foreach I need to print the number of items from array

Comment: Don't now if you understand my idea

Comment: It is quite hard to understand, to be honest. Could you try to explain that better?

Comment: @LukasMeine, I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array Slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

```
<?php
 $numberOfItems = 3 // How many items would you like to select?
 $first_items = array_slice(lastviewedarticles, 0, $numberOfItems);
 return $first_items;
```